# Xerces and Eclipse Disagree : no declaration found for element

Tags: xml-validation

I have an XSD and an XML file. Eclipse (version 4.7.3) validates these files with no errors or warnings (and, yes, Eclipse is validating the XML against the XSD). However, when I hand the XSD and the XML files to Xerces (with my XercesDOMParser validation set to Always), I get this error:

```
no declaration found for element 'g:tssConnections'
```

I have searched all over, and I cannot seem to find anything that is relevant. Can anyone tell me my error? Here is the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://gecoinc.com"
 xmlns:geco="http://gecoinc.com"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="ipAddrType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create tags that contain a single
        IPv4 address. This type may used for both multicast
        and unicast addresses.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="ipPortType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create tags that contain TCP or UDP port
        numbers.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
      <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="65535"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="serverType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create variables that hold information
        needed to create a server endpoint.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="remotePeerPort" type="geco:ipPortType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="clientType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create variables that hold information
        needed to create a client endpoint.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="remotePeerIp" type="geco:ipAddrType" />
      <xs:element name="remotePeerPort" type="geco:ipPortType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="endpointType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create variables that hold information
        needed to create an endpoint. Either a client or a server may
        be created.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="serverParams" type="geco:serverType"/>
      <xs:element name="clientParams" type="geco:clientType"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="transportType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="tcp"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="udp"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="connectionType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create structures that hold all of the
        information that is needed for a single connection
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="isServer" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="endpointParams" type="geco:endpointType"/>
      <xs:element name="connectionName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="transport" type="geco:transportType"/>
      <xs:element
          name="multicastIntfAddr"
          type="geco:ipAddrType"
          minOccurs="0"
          maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="connectionListType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        This type is used to create a list of connections.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element
       name="connection"
       type="geco:connectionType"
       minOccurs="1"
       maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="tssConnections" type="geco:connectionListType" />

</xs:schema>
```

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<g:tssConnections
 xmlns:g="http://gecoinc.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://gecoinc.com oss.xsd">

        <g:connection>
                <g:connectionName>CM_LOAD_PRESET_OUT</g:connectionName>
                <g:isServer>false</g:isServer>
                <g:endpointParams>
                        <g:clientParams>
                                <g:remotePeerIp>224.5.5.5</g:remotePeerIp>
                                <g:remotePeerPort>11101</g:remotePeerPort>
                        </g:clientParams>
                </g:endpointParams>
                <g:transport>udp</g:transport>
                <g:multicastIntfAddr>10.0.2.15</g:multicastIntfAddr>
        </g:connection>

</g:tssConnections>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I would suspect it is not finding your xsd. Makes sure it is loading correctly

Comment: Any reason you have this in your ns declaration? xmlns:geco="http://gecoinc.com" you just gave that uri two names the default and geco.. I don't think this is a problem but just wondering why?

Comment: Just being complete here. I did indeed verify that it was finding and loading my XSD, by using strace on the process. See my answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem. It turns out that the error message coming out of Xerces was very misleading. I had to turn on several aspects of validation in the parser, as follows:

```
domParser->setDoNamespaces( true );
domParser->setDoSchema( true );
domParser->setHandleMultipleImports ( true );
domParser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking( true );
```

Once I did that, the error went away. I hope that the above can help someone.